# How to create a wrapper helper around Url.Content helper function?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to create a wrapper around this existing helper:

```
@Content.Url("...")
```

**How can I create a helper to wrap this and add a parameter to it?**

My Controller has a property:

```
public bool IsAdmin {get; set;}
```

I want to somehow reference this value from my controller and use it like:

```
@MyContent.Url("...", IsAdmin)
```

How can I do this?  Is the only way to add `IsAdmin` to my `ViewModel`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either add `IsAdmin` to your model or make it a static property that stores the value in `HttpContext.Current.Items`. Alternatively it can read the value dynamically from `HttpContext.Request`.

```
public static bool IsAdmin
{
    get { return (HttpContext.Current.Items["IsAdmin"] as bool?) ?? false; }
    set { HttpContext.Current.Items["IsAdmin"] = value; }
}
```

You can create a custom extension method like this

```
public static Content(this UrlHelper helper, string contentPath, bool isAdmin)
{
    // do something with isAdmin
    helper.Content(contentPath);
}
```

Comment: helper.Content is the same as @Content.Url ??

Comment: yes, `helper.Url` would be invoking the original implementation of `@Content.Url`.

Comment: so if I make IsAdmin static on my controller, the view page can access it then?

Comment: Yes, static properties can be accessed from the view page.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/532513/ASP-NET-MVC-Url-Content-extended-with-force-update) is a very good example of what you are looking for:

```
public class UrlHelperEx : UrlHelper
{
    #region Constants
    private const string c_VERSION_FORMAT = "{0}?v={1}";
    #endregion

    #region Initialization
    public UrlHelperEx(RequestContext requestContext)
        : base(requestContext)
    {
    }
    #endregion

    #region Public methods
    public string Content(string contentPath,bool forceupdate=false)
    {
        var content = base.Content(contentPath);

        if (!forceupdate) {
            return content.ToString();
        }
        else
        { 
            Version version = WebHelper.GetApplicationVersion(this.RequestContext.HttpContext);
            return string.Format(c_VERSION_FORMAT, content
                    , version.ToString());
        }
    }
    #endregion  
}
```